# WireMock not mapping request by body contains

Tags: wiremock

My http request send to this: `https://myhost.com/ap`

My http request with body :

{

```
  "Body": {
    "CommandName": "GetApplicationProfile"
  },
  "Header": {
    "Command": "GetApplicationProfile",
  }
}
```

I want to mapping this request by WireMock.

Here WireMock's mapping file.

```
    {
  "request": {
    "url": "/my_host/ap",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "contains": "GetApplicationProfile"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "get_profile.json"
  }
}
```

I start wireMock like this:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar --port 8080 --enable-browser-proxying -verbose
```

But when request was started the WireMock not map this request. Nothing happened.
why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you shouldn't have the hostname in the `url` part. This is not needed. Your example message can be sent and will be matched using the following rule.

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "/app",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "contains": "GetApplicationProfile"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "body": "ddd"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you tested this and what you've observed?

Comment: From android device I start application that create http request. WiFi settings on device set to proxy over WireMock. WireMock start on my local  machine. Device connect to my local machine via USB. And when from android device sent http request the WireMock success intercept request. But this request (on topic) it can't intercept.

Comment: Have you tried it first with a simple Postman or Insomia request?

Comment: Not, I'm not use yet. How I can do this?

Comment: Smsniff can be downloaded from the nirsoft website and does not need any install. The only thing to check is that the right network card is selected. In this case it should default to the loop back adapter, which is fine if you use local host.

Answer (score 0):

The URL should not contain the host name. It should only contain the resource path.

The url format should start with "/" e.g. `/https://myhost.com/ap`.
Now if u r trying this on localhost then the URL should be `localhost:<port>/https://myhost.com/ap`.

The file should be present at `src/test/resources/__files`
If not it will give error file not present.

Comment: Not help. Same result. Wiremock not react.

Comment: What do u mean by WireMock not react? Can u share the response from wiremock?

Comment: No response from WireMock. Not any reaction

Comment: If u r using WireMock for proxy purpose then Proxy Base url should be present in response `proxyBaseUrl" : "http://otherhost.com/approot` and the URL provided in request should be relative.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues here:
 1. you need to remove the host name from the url in the mapping file.
 2. your request is HTTPS which means you need to start your wiremock port with https: --https-port 8080 or you change your request to HTTP